# Dynamically changing jqgrid's direction

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid which I want to show dynamically on 2 directions when the default one is ltr.

I want to be able to change the grid direction to rtl and to reload its content on a button click.

How can I dynamically change the grid's direction?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using `$('#grid').setGridParam({direction: rtl\ltr})` according to the direction I want , and the grid's content is changed, but the columns are the same as they were. is there a way to change the columns direction as well?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a button with an id of button and a jqGrid with an id of grid then:

```
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#grid').getGridParam('direction') == 'ltr')
         $('#grid').setGridParam({direction: 'rtl'});
    else
         $('#grid').setGridParam({direction: 'ltr'});

    $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

You can read about the grid methods (getGridParam and setGridParam [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) and the direction property of jqGrid [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

Comment: I tested your code now, and it works partially - the grid's content direction changes , but the columns are not changing. I want the column to change according to the direction. is this possible? thank's again.